# Python to json put keys with members' names not properties' names

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to convert Python object to JSON and I'm doing this with member function like

```
def to_json(self):
    return json.dumps(self.__dict__)
```

Problem is that I have member _name and property name

```
@property
def name(self):
    return self._name
@name.setter
def name(self, value):
   self._name = some_validation_ove_name(value)
```

and in result JSON I get data with key `_name` but I wanted to be `name`. Is this possible without manual creation of JSON ?

Answer (score 2):

Possible.  Of course.  What is the best method is the better question.  This should work for you in this example, but may not be the ideal solution if you have other cases:

```
def to_json(self):
    return json.dumps({k.strip('_'): v for k, v in self.__dict__.items()})
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
import json

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "foo"
        self.__bar__ = "__bar__"
        self.baz = "_baz"

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value

    def to_json(self):
        return json.dumps({k.strip('_'): v for k, v in self.__dict__.items()})

foo = Foo()
foo.name = "name"
print foo.to_json()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{"baz": "_baz", "foo": "foo", "bar": "__bar__", "name": "name"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could creat a dictionary with the names you want and encode that into JSON